# Base64 encode/decode Library for c++ cross-platform?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, base64

I've looked on Google and I can't seem to find a simple encode/decode base64 library which takes a string and returns a string.

Anyone know of any libraries that can be used on both Windows and Linux?

Answer (score 2):

Seriously?  A simple Google search turns up this:

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/QuickTimeStreamingServer/QuickTimeStreamingServer-452/CommonUtilitiesLib/base64.c

There's a corresponding .h header file [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/QuickTimeStreamingServer/QuickTimeStreamingServer-452/CommonUtilitiesLib/base64.h).

Looks very easy to use:

```
 char* data = // your initialization here
 int data_length = // your data length here
 int encoded_data_length = int Base64encode_len(data_length);
 char* base64_string = malloc(encoded_data_length);

 Base64encode(base64_string, data, data_length);
 // "base64_string" is a null terminated string that is an encoding of the
 // binary data pointed to by "data"
```

The corresponding converstion back from base64 string to decoded binary data looks easy too:

```
char* data = NULL;
int data_length = 0;
int alloc_length = Base64decode_len(base64_string);
some_random_data = malloc(alloc_length);
data_length = Base64decode(data, base64_string);
```

Comment: I was looking for an actual library where I don't see the implementation, i can just include it into the project. All i should be able to see is the external functions, like libcurl for example.

Comment: @suzanaydin - it doesn't get any easier than this. Just take the above referenced .c and .h file and copy both into your project.  That's all you need to do.  If you want, you can create a separate project explicitly for building base64.c into a standalone library. Then include the resulting .lib file (and .h file) into your main project.

Comment: getting an error "Error 1 error LNK1561: entry point must be defined"

Comment: actually fixed it by changing the project to static lib

Comment: Upon looking at my other files in the lib directory of my entire project, all of them have the extension .a, but this one i just created is .lib. Do you know how i can change this?